# making a program that will check if the input is equal to the word declared

Tags: turbo-c++

So here's the program with all the declarations. I'm trying to make a program like the game text twist.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

float scorer71(float);

float scorer7l(float score)
{
int newscore;
newscore=score+50;
return newscore;
}

struct level1
{
char martial[7];
char marital[7];
char input[100];
int counter, length, holder;
};


main()
{
float score=0,zero=0;
struct level1 words;
int executor_martial=0;
int executor_marital=0;

clrscr();

words.holder=0;

while (score<100)
{
gotoxy(2,20);
printf("Enter a word:");
gets(words.input);
words.length=strlen(words.input);
```

if i run the program the score is already 50 and martial is already printed even if i haven't inputed the word martial.

```
if (executor_martial<1)
{
    strcpy(words.martial,"martial");

    for (words.counter=0; words.counter<=words.length; words.counter++)
    {
        if (words.input[words.counter]==words.martial[words.counter])
        words.holder++;
    }
        if (words.length==words.holder)
        {
        score=score+scorer7l(zero);
        gotoxy(2,21);
        printf("%.0f",score);
        gotoxy(70,13);
        printf("martial");
        executor_martial++;
        }
}

else if (executor_marital<1)
{
    strcpy(words.marital,"marital");

    for (words.counter=0; words.counter<=words.length; words.counter++)
    {
        if (words.input[words.counter]==words.marital[words.counter])
        words.holder++;
    }

        if (words.length==words.holder)
        {
            score=score+scorer7l(zero);
            gotoxy(2,21);
            printf("%.0f",score);
            gotoxy(70,14);
            printf("marital");
            executor_marital++;
        }
}
}
}
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is that the whole program?

Comment: What is `print`, `words`, `string`(include `<string>`)? Did you define them somewhere else and forgot to `#include`? And where is `main()` ??